# Widgets not expanding on wordpress 3.3 widget dashbord

Tags: widgets, admin, dashboard, register-sidebar, troubleshooting

I updated to WordPress 3.3 (manual update) and cleaned browser cache.

Widgets dashbord stop working when tring to expand dynamic sidebars for custom theme when it works for previous wordpress 3.2 installation (using register sidebar on functions.php)

I have tried to install Hotfix 0.8 exension and now it works for twentyten theme but not for my custom theme.

What can I do?

Comment: Does your custom theme replace the built-in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

I installed w3 total cache plugin and cleared my browser cache.  Wish I had of done this pre deleting some forms!

Answer (score -1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/
this FIX it! Cheers! :)